# LSTM predicting time series yields odd results

Tags: machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to predict time series data for the next few days looking at past few days, using Keras. My label data is target values for multiple future days, regression model has multiple output neurons (the "direct approach" for time series).

Here is test data with predictions for 10 days, using 60 days history.

[10 days prediction for test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/861xK.png)

As you can see, future values for all days are about the same. I've spent quite some time on it, and must admit that I'm probably missing something with respect to LSTM...

Here is training data with prediction:

[10 days prediction for training data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCDP6.png)

In order to confirm that I'm preparing data properly, I've created a "tracking data set" which I used to visualize data transformations. Here it is...

Data set:

```python
Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,OpenInt
111,112,113,114,115,0
121,122,123,124,125,0
131,132,133,134,135,0
141,142,143,144,145,0
151,152,153,154,155,0
161,162,163,164,165,0
171,172,173,174,175,0
181,182,183,184,185,0
191,192,193,194,195,0
201,202,203,204,205,0
211,212,213,214,215,0
221,222,223,224,225,0
231,232,233,234,235,0
241,242,243,244,245,0
251,252,253,254,255,0
261,262,263,264,265,0
271,272,273,274,275,0
281,282,283,284,285,0
291,292,293,294,295,0
```

Training set using 2 days history, predicting 3 days future values (I used different values of history days and future days, and it all makes sense to me), **without** feature scaling in order to visualize data transformations:

```python
X train (6, 2, 5)
[[[111 112 113 114 115]
  [121 122 123 124 125]]

 [[121 122 123 124 125]
  [131 132 133 134 135]]

 [[131 132 133 134 135]
  [141 142 143 144 145]]

 [[141 142 143 144 145]
  [151 152 153 154 155]]

 [[151 152 153 154 155]
  [161 162 163 164 165]]

 [[161 162 163 164 165]
  [171 172 173 174 175]]]
Y train (6, 3)
[[131 141 151]
 [141 151 161]
 [151 161 171]
 [161 171 181]
 [171 181 191]
 [181 191 201]]
```

Test set

```python
X test (6, 2, 5)
[[[201 202 203 204 205]
  [211 212 213 214 215]]

 [[211 212 213 214 215]
  [221 222 223 224 225]]

 [[221 222 223 224 225]
  [231 232 233 234 235]]

 [[231 232 233 234 235]
  [241 242 243 244 245]]

 [[241 242 243 244 245]
  [251 252 253 254 255]]

 [[251 252 253 254 255]
  [261 262 263 264 265]]]
Y test (6, 3)
[[221 231 241]
 [231 241 251]
 [241 251 261]
 [251 261 271]
 [261 271 281]
 [271 281 291]]
```

Model:

```python
def CreateRegressor(self,
                    optimizer='adam', 
                    activation='tanh', # RNN activation
                    init_mode='glorot_uniform', 
                    hidden_neurons=50,
                    dropout_rate=0.0, 
                    weight_constraint=0,
                    stateful=False,
                    # SGD parameters
                    learn_rate=0.01, 
                    momentum=0):
    kernel_constraint = maxnorm(weight_constraint) if weight_constraint > 0 else None
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(units=hidden_neurons, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=init_mode, kernel_constraint=kernel_constraint,
                   return_sequences=True, input_shape=(self.X_train.shape[1], self.X_train.shape[2]), stateful=stateful))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

    model.add(LSTM(units=hidden_neurons, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=init_mode, kernel_constraint=kernel_constraint,
                   return_sequences=True, stateful=stateful))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

    model.add(LSTM(units=hidden_neurons, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=init_mode, kernel_constraint=kernel_constraint,
                   return_sequences=True, stateful=stateful))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

    model.add(LSTM(units=hidden_neurons, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=init_mode,  kernel_constraint=kernel_constraint,
                   return_sequences=False, stateful=stateful))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

    model.add(Dense(units=self.y_train.shape[1]))

    if (optimizer == 'SGD'):
        optimizer = SGD(lr=learn_rate, momentum=momentum)

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model
```

...which I create with these params:

```python
    self.CreateRegressor(optimizer = 'adam', hidden_neurons = 100)
```

... and then fit like this:

```python
    self.regressor.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
```

... and predict:

```python
    y_pred = self.regressor.predict(X_test)
```

... or

```python
    y_pred_train = self.regressor.predict(X_train)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you need to scale.....and then 'un-scale' your outputs

Comment: @MitchWheat i do that for actual data. I just disabled it for this dataset to visualize my data transformations, so I can confirm that my data arrays are generated properly.